# Firebase realtime database retrive data by uid and put it to Varable kotlin android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

How to retrieve data from the Realtime database?
I want to get user specific data search by uid witch is also a child of the user database.
I need retrieve all data for specific user ID
 "day","month"etc. values as variables.

[image: Database structure]

I've got data in firebase put by:

DatabaseRow class:

```
data class DatabaseRow (
    val id:String = "",
    val names: String= "",
    val lastname: String="",
    val day: String="",
    val month: String="",
    val year:String=""
)
```

firebase input:

```
 val firebaseInput = DatabaseRow(user,names,lastname,day,month,year)
        userRef.child("$user").setValue(firebaseInput)
```

to retrieve data I'm using this code:

```
  auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        FirebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser()!!

        val uid = auth.getUid()!!

        val fireBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
        userRef = fireBase.getReference("users")
        val ordersRef = userRef.child("$uid").equalTo("$uid")


val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                for (ds in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    val username = ds.child("day").getValue(String::class.java)
                    Log.d("DataBaseGetName",username)
                    this@Main2Activity.testTextView.text = username 
                }
            }

            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
                Log.d("Data", databaseError.getMessage()) //Don't ignore errors!
            }
        }
   ordersRef.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener)
```

that are database rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": true,
         "users":{
            "$uid":{
               ".write": "auth.uid === $uid",
               ".read": "auth.uid === $uid"
               },     
    "users":{
        ".indexOn": [".value","id","names","lastname","day","month","year"]
    },
   }
  }  
}
```

Comment: Please explain what is wrong with above code and why you use `this@Main2Activity.textTextView.text` ?

Comment: Tank You for grammar  edit

Comment: I didn't retrieve any data in logs, or anywhere. I'm using text view trying to see if any data were retrieved from database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're receiving the `uid`, you're trying to compare it with the database `uid`. The `uid` is always different.

```
val ordersRef = userRef.child("$uid")
val valueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        val username = dataSnapshot.child("names").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("DataBaseGetName",username)
    }

    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        Log.d("Data", databaseError.getMessage()) //Don't ignore errors!
    }
}
ordersRef.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener)
```

Comment: Uid is different for every user because it's firebase  authentication by email. And app saves data under logged in user Uid.

Comment: yes that's why you don't need to put equalto when your trying to retrieve single user data. Equalto is used when the multiple users hold similar type data

Comment: When I try to retrieve data by Uid child Uid child is not indexed and database won't read data and puts warning of use unspecified  index

Comment: Can You help me with using them?